# Accessing parent column info in a sub query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a sub query to have in a larger query, The subquery I am writting needs to get a.workorder_id from the main column

This one works ( Notice x.workorder_id = '805' )

```
SELECT a.* , 
( SELECT SUM( maxes ) qty 
  FROM  ( 
     SELECT MAX( qty ) maxes 
     FROM `rework_line` x 
     WHERE x.workorder_id = '805' 
     GROUP BY x.size 
  ) as tba 
) tmpsum 
FROM rework_line a 
WHERE a.workorder_id = '805' 
GROUP BY a.workorder_id
```

Yet when I change x.workorder_id = a.workorder_id it no longer works and tells me

**#1054 - Unknown column 'a.workorder_id' in 'where clause'**

```
SELECT a.* , 
( SELECT SUM( maxes ) 
  qty FROM  ( 
     SELECT MAX( qty ) maxes 
     FROM `mtborah_rework_line` x 
     WHERE x.workorder_id = a.workorder_id 
     GROUP BY x.size 
  ) as tba 
) tmpsum 
FROM mtborah_rework_line a 
WHERE a.workorder_id = '805' 
GROUP BY a.workorder_id
```

I am sure it is something simple I forgot, but in all my googing I can not find out how to do it, I also tryed asking in the mysql room on freenode, and all they would say is to rewrite it as a join, which is not possible due to the query I am having it in If I re-join to this table it will through off my counts and sum's

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something, but why don't you rewrite this using a subquery in a join instead of the correlated subquery:

```
SELECT a.*, qty
FROM mtborah_rework_line a 
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT SUM(maxes) qty, workorder_id
  FROM
  (
    SELECT MAX( qty ) maxes, x.workorder_id
    FROM `mtborah_rework_line` x 
    GROUP BY x.size, x.workorder_id
  ) m
  GROUP BY workorder_id
) q
  on a.workorder_id = q.workorder_id
WHERE a.workorder_id = '805';
```

Or even this way:

```
SELECT a.*, SUM(maxes) qty
FROM mtborah_rework_line a 
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT MAX(qty) maxes, x.workorder_id
  FROM `mtborah_rework_line` x 
  GROUP BY x.size, x.workorder_id
) q
  on a.workorder_id = q.workorder_id
WHERE a.workorder_id = '805' 
GROUP BY a.workorder_id;
```

Comment: The first one worked thanks ( the second one would not, due to it adding 5 more lines that would be summed up in my other sum() statements

Comment: @TimHolum glad it is working.  If this answer is helpful or any answer to your questions are helpful, then be sure to accept it via the checkmark to the left of it. It will help future visitors to the site and you will get site rep for accepting. :)

Comment: Yup, I had to wait the 5 minutes to accept it :), Thanks again